# SQL Server - View a list of Materialized Views (Snapshots)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, materialized-views

Is there a way to view a list of all of the materialized views inside of a database?

Answer (score 2):

You could query metadata tables:

```
SELECT v.name
FROM sys.views v
JOIN sys.indexes i
  ON v.object_id = i.object_id
 AND i.[type] = 1;  -- clustered
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=329feaabd91b24765336d5f48cc90c33)**